# How to append element to a 4th element child using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have section in which I have slider now I want to append element to a 4th element   inside its children.

Here is my HTML

Here is what I have tried so far

```
 $(".owl-stage>div:nth-child(4)").after("<div>inserted div</div>");
```

What do I need to change to get what I want?

Comment: What happens, when you execute that code?

Comment: Nothing is added :(

Comment: $(".owl-stage>div:nth-child(4)") should be  $(".owl-item>div:nth-child(4)")

Comment: @Gerard No. The selector should be correct. He uses the `>` to access the direct children of '.owl-stage'.

Comment: @Gerard No, That is wrong and not working

Comment: @user9964622 Please note you say append element to the 4'th but you are using `.after()`. That will not append it but place it after the element.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen if you don't mind can you show that on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to `append` some element to the 4'th element use `$(".owl-stage>div:nth-child(4) .item:eq(1) .text-center").append("<div>inserted div</div>");`

Now if you run the demo and scroll all the way down and inspect `inserted div` then you can see it's appended to `<div class="owl-item active" style="width: 1140px;">`

**Demo**

```js
$(".owl-stage>div:nth-child(4) .item:eq(1) .text-center").append("<div>inserted div</div>");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="owl-stage">
  <div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 1140px;">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="row sec-padding flex-center">
        <div class="col-md-6 mb-50px z-index-1">

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
          <img alt="img" src="https://videommerce.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/grafika_do_filmu2.png">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 1140px;">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="row sec-padding flex-center">
        <div class="col-md-6 mb-50px z-index-1">

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
          <img alt="img" src="https://videommerce.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Grow-your-brand.png">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="owl-item" style="width: 1140px;">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="row sec-padding flex-center">
        <div class="col-md-6 mb-50px z-index-1">

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
          <img alt="img" src="https://videommerce.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/videommerce_share_your_story.png">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="owl-item active" style="width: 1140px;">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="row sec-padding flex-center">
        <div class="col-md-6 mb-50px z-index-1">

          <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
            <img alt="img" src="https://videommerce.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/grafika_do_filmu2.png">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="owl-item" style="width: 1140px;">
      <div class="item">
        <div class="row sec-padding flex-center">
          <div class="col-md-6 mb-50px z-index-1">

          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
            <img alt="img" src="https://videommerce.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Grow-your-brand.png">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 1140px;">
      <div class="item">
        <div class="row sec-padding flex-center">
          <div class="col-md-6 mb-50px z-index-1">

            <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
              <img alt="img" src="https://videommerce.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/videommerce_share_your_story.png">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 1140px;">
        <div class="item">
          <div class="row sec-padding flex-center">
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-50px z-index-1">

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
              <img alt="img" src="https://videommerce.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/grafika_do_filmu2.png">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @carson can you delete images links on the solution you provided? thanks

Comment: @TheDeadMan what image do you want to delete

Answer (score 0):

**You can append as below** using `.owl-item` and with index of child element, you want to insert after 4th element so you can use 3 index

```js
$(".owl-stage div.owl-item:eq(4)").after("<div>inserted div</div>");
```